# how to run the built in design tool for mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c

one of my friends suggested me to Select the project file within X Code (at the very top of the Groups and Files pane) go to Design->Class Model->Quick Model, but the problem is i am using latest version of x code and i don't have design menu in my files pane...can any one explain how to run the built in design tool for mac..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu bar, choose File > New > New File....  In the dialog, choose Core Data under the iOS heading, then choose the Data Model icon and click Next.  Give your new file a name (the default is "Model") and click Create.

Now choose Model.xcdatamodel (or whatever you named it) in your file list.  It'll be empty but you can add entities and relationships.  If you want the diagram view, click the right button of the multi-button labeled "Editor Style" in the lower right corner of the window.

Comment: I think he's talking about the "quick model" functionality we had in Xcode 3, which went away in Xcode 4.  This  is not related to Core  Data.

Comment: Except that those class models weren’t Core Data models: they were visual representations of arbitrary classes. Here’s an example: http://www.permadi.com/blog/2009/06/xcode-tips/

Comment: I never knew about that.  Ha ha ha.  If it's still available I'd love to know how to access it. :)

Comment: Yeah, it was neat but I think it’s not available in Xcode 4. :-/